# Cypress tests are getting stuck indefinitely sometimes in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. Is there any workaround?

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress, pipeline, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Cypress tests are running perfectly in local, but when I run them in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, tests get stuck in between after 2-3 test cases, and finally they time out. How to overcome this situation?

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: No error messages, just three blinking dots and the execution is stuck. I'm using Cypress 4.11.0 and running the tests in Chrome inside a docker image, in Gitlab pipeline.

Comment: @PallabeePutatunda did you manage to fix that?